# WPF Awesomium - custom ResourceInterceptor wont allow local files to be loaded from disk

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

i have added my own custom Resource Interceptor to Awesomiums Webcore.  I use it to load a local html file, manipulate it and then return it.

However this HTML file references other files on disk and I always get the error - something like

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/awesomium project/bin/Debug/Resources/Html/css/myCss.css

This happens whether I return a file or a byte[] as my ResourceResponse.  I have the WebPreferences set up as follows

```
return new WebPreferences()
            {
                UniversalAccessFromFileURL = true,
                FileAccessFromFileURL = true,
                SmoothScrolling = true,
            };
```

I had this working using Awesomiums custom data sources but I need to provide our own prefix i.e. I can't use asset://.  i'm not sure why this isn't working from the IResourceInterceptor.  Any ideas?

Here is my imlementation of the Resource interceptor

```
    public bool OnFilterNavigation(NavigationRequest request)
    {
        return false;//not handled
    }

    public ResourceResponse OnRequest(ResourceRequest request)
    {
        var path = request.Url.ToString();
        ResourceResponse response = null;

        if (path.StartsWith(@"myCustomPrefix://"))
        {
            response = _firstHandler.HandleRequest(path.Replace(@"myCustomPrefix://", string.Empty));
        }

        return response;
    }
```

> Edit: _firstHandler is a chain of command pattern.  I could potentially do many things with the request so I have a handler for each one.  I would like to say the handlers work.  If I set them to create a file on disk they create that file - if I load up the html file from disk directly in the awesomium browser it is loaded correctly. It is only an issue when I return it as a ResourceResponse(filepath) or ResourceResponse(byte[], intPtr, mimetype) that it says it can't load the other files the HTML references locally.

Comment: whats `_firstHandler`, and what does it do?

Comment: Its a chain of command pattern to handle the request - see my edit.  Let me know if you want to see one of the handlers. Thanks

Comment: How do you read the files? You should be able to open a file Stream (plain C#), read the bytes from it and put them into the response.